# Conflict in Fluxx

Tags: fluxx

Player A and Player B both have 5 Keepers in play.

Player B has 1 Creeper (Prevents Player B from winning)

Player A plays the goal card 5 Keepers which goes like this (goal cards, are the criteria met to win)

"If someone has 5 or more Keepers on the table, then the player with the most Keepers in play wins.
In case of a tie, continue playing until a clear winner emerges."

Does Player A win or does the game continue?

Comment: Have you sent your question to Looney Labs? thelab@looneylabs.com They should be able to give you a definitive answer.

Answer (score 12):

> *Does Player A win or does the game continue?*
>
> In case of a tie, continue playing until a clear winner emerges.

There's clearly a tie in the number of Keepers, so you must continue playing.

Player A is not ***the** player with the most Keepers*. He's merely ***a** player with the most Keepers*. It is explicitly stated that the game does not end in the event of a tie.

It could have been written "If someone has 5 or more Keepers on the table, and if a player has more Keepers than any other players, that player wins."

To win, one must have 5 or more Keepers [*satisfied*], and one must be the player with the most Keepers [*not satisfied*].

Player B can't win because he has insufficient Keepers and because he has a Creeper.

Player A can't win because he has insufficient Keepers.

GendoIkari's answer is self-contradictory. "Until a clear winner emerges" only applies if the players keep playing, but he suggests that Player A should win rather than keep playing. That rules out letting Player A win. The only way around that self-contradiction is to keep playing until the tie is broken (or the goal changes, etc).

Answer (score 1):

I think that "until a clear winner emerges" is met due to the creeper. Player A should win, as player B cannot be a winner.

Comment: Your answer is self contradictory. "Until a clear winner emerges" only applies if you keep playing, but you said "Player A" should win rather than keep playing.

Comment: @atk, He does not satisfy the winning condition. 1) He's got 5 or more Keepers [satisfied], and 2) he's the player with the most Keepers [not satisfied]. A tie is explicitly called out as not meeting the winning condition.

Comment: @atk, What part of the card allows you to ignore Player B's Keepers when you check if Player A has the most? Player A is not *the player with the most Keepers*. He's merely **a** player with the most Keepers. It is explicitly stated that ties does not end the game.

Comment: @ikegami Upon reconsideration, I now agree with you.

Comment: @ikegami, I agree now as well, given the wording. However, I would be surprised if that's what the intention was, I think it much more likely that this was a rules oversite (it wouldn't be the first time Fluxx has done this, see "x=x+1 and hand limit 0). It seems that the intention behind "in case of a tie" was to deal with when there would be more than 1 winner. Keep in mind that that goal card was created back when Creepers didn't exists. But, as it stands, I'd have to agree with you.